# In Graph API, when are the "Call Started" and "Call Ended" system messages generated?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a subscription to a particular chat's messages (/chats/{chat-id}/messages), and according to the documentation this subscription should get system messages, as listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/system-messages#supported-system-message-events.

I get some of these messages as expected, but not the Call Started or Call Ended ones when the users in the chat make a call to each other. So, under what circumstances are these messages generated?

Comment: Accorsing this: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/14709#issuecomment-962076101 Notifications for some system message are not implemented in v1.0 but it's not clear which ones but looks like that CallStarted and CallEnded are one of them.

Comment: This is by design and is not present in v1.